# How to fix "static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8" in Scala application?

Tags: scala, java-8, sbt, amazon-cloudwatch

I wrote the following code:

```scala
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.CloudWatchLogsClient

class Test() extends CloudWatchLogsClient {
  CloudWatchLogsClient.builder().build()
  def close():Unit = {
    println("test")
  }

  def serviceName(): String  = "serviceName"
  CloudWatchLogsClient.create()
}
```

When it comes to compiling , I get the following error:

```
Static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8
  CloudWatchLogsClient.builder().build()
```

Finally, I used the following dependencies in my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies += "software.amazon.awssdk" % "cloudwatch" % "2.15.40",
libraryDependencies += "software.amazon.awssdk" % "cloudwatchlogs" % "2.15.40"
```

Java version is 1.8, and Scala version is 2.11.12. Any idea, how to fix this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add the following into your `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions in ThisBuild += "-target:jvm-1.8"
```

There is a similar question asking about the same error at Gradle at [Static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49213620/2359227).

Comment: What should be added in the case of Maven? I tried the <argScalc> plugin but didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62694412/2359227

Comment: It's the same actually. Changing scala version will help?